# Pandas: How to remove the index column after groupby and unstack?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got trouble removing the index column in pandas after groupby and unstack a DataFrame.

My original DataFrame looks like this:

```
example = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2016-12', '2016-12', '2017-01', '2017-01', '2017-02', '2017-02', '2017-02'], 'customer': [123, 456, 123, 456, 123, 456, 456], 'sales': [10.5, 25.2, 6.8, 23.4, 29.5, 23.5, 10.4]})
example.head(10)
```

output:

|  | date | customer | sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2016-12 | 123 | 10.5 |
| 1 | 2016-12 | 456 | 25.2 |
| 2 | 2017-01 | 123 | 6.8 |
| 3 | 2017-01 | 456 | 23.4 |
| 4 | 2017-2 | 123 | 29.5 |
| 5 | 2017-2 | 456 | 23.5 |
| 6 | 2017-2 | 456 | 10.4 |

Note that it's possible to have multiple sales for one customer per month (like in row 5 and 6).

My aim is to convert the DataFrame into an aggregated DataFrame like this:

| customer | 2016-12 | 2017-01 | 2017-02 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 10.5 | 6.8 | 29.5 |
| 234 | 25.2 | 23.4 | 33.9 |

**My solution so far:**

```
example = example[['date', 'customer', 'sales']].groupby(['date', 'customer']).sum().unstack('date')
example.head(10)
```

output:

|  | sales |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **date** | **2016-12** | **2017-01** | **2017-02** |
| **customer** |  |  |  |
| 123 | 10.5 | 6.8 | 29.5 |
| 234 | 25.2 | 23.4 | 33.9 |

```
example = example['sales'].reset_index(level=[0])
example.head(10)
```

output:

| date | customer | 2016-12 | 2017-01 | 2017-02 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **0** | 123 | 10.5 | 6.8 | 29.5 |
| **1** | 234 | 25.2 | 23.4 | 33.9 |

At this point I'm unable to remove the "date" column:

```
example.reset_index(drop = True)
example.head()
```

output:

| date | customer | 2016-12 | 2017-01 | 2017-02 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **0** | 123 | 10.5 | 6.8 | 29.5 |
| **1** | 234 | 25.2 | 23.4 | 33.9 |

It just stays the same. Have you got any ideas?

Comment: add a  rename_axis: ``example.reset_index(drop=True).rename_axis(columns=None)``. generally, you coud try this as well : ``example[["date", "customer", "sales"]].groupby(["date", "customer"]).sum().unstack("date").droplevel(0, axis="columns").rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()``

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An alternative to your solution, but the key is just to add a `rename_axis(columns = None)`, as the `date` is the name for the columns axis:

```
(example[["date", "customer", "sales"]]
.groupby(["date", "customer"])
.sum()
.unstack("date")
.droplevel(0, axis="columns")
.rename_axis(columns=None)
.reset_index())

    customer    2016-12 2017-01 2017-02
0   123          10.5   6.8     29.5
1   456          25.2   23.4    33.9
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @sammywemmy. That is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

Why not directly go with `pivot_table`?

```
(example
 .pivot_table('sales', index='customer', columns="date", aggfunc='sum')
 .rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index())
    
    customer    2016-12 2017-01 2017-02
0   123         10.5    6.8     29.5
1   456         25.2    23.4    33.9
```

Comment: This is better I guess +1.

Comment: yea. pivot_table abstracts away many of the steps. Sometimes though, you have to check for speed, as pivot_table sometimes can be slower than you doing the manual longer steps of groupby and the rest. For this example, pivot_table is about 2x slower. I might be wrong; it may increase as the data size increases. one advantage of pivot_table though is that it can natively handle duplicate indices, whereas unstack you would need to manually create unique indices (cumcount). Well, abstraction vs speed